# Repairing USB drive

Tags: udev, usb-storage, fsck

I'm attempting to repair a USB drive that I would like to use for booting Linux on my laptop. The drive was removed from the laptop while it was formatting and is unreadable now. However, if I open the terminal and run

```
$ lsblk
```

I am able to see the drive show up in the list. It is listed as "sdb". I ran `fsck` and this was returned:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for david: 
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

or

e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo es2fsck -b 8193 sdb
```

and

```
$ sudo es2fsck -b 32768 sdb
```

to no avail. Something was returned, but the terminal closed and I don't have the result. I then attempted to zero the device with:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

and nothing has been returned. Any suggestions on what I should do to make this drive work?

Comment: Someone said this is not a unix or linux question. Is there a better forum for this question?

Comment: superuser might be more apt. I can migrate it there if you want.

Comment: Since you 0'ed the whole device you have to reformat it.

Comment: Ah. Does that mean the drive could fry if I let it run long enough?

Comment: I mean the port itself.

Comment: I have never managed to fry a USB port with a bad USB pendrive. I think the risk is very small.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378260/creating-a-standalone-bootable-usb-drive/378275#378275). Steps 1-2 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After wiping the drive (with the `dd` command line, or at least the head end of the drive), you should be able to create a new partition table, partitions and file systems. It is often enough to wipe the first mibibyte to remove data, that might confuse partitioning tools. [You may need something else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

If you have a graphical desktop environment, it is convenient to use **`gparted`** for this task. Otherwise you can do the partitioning work with `parted` and then use other tools to create file systems, for example `mkfs.ext4` for the linux file system `ext4`.